# Sound Effect Not Playing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, audio, audiotoolbox

I am implementing AudioToolbox framework to try to play a sound effect. Here is my code:
I declared a    SystemSoundID called explode

```
  NSURL *explodeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                            pathForResource:@"Explosion" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)
                                 explodeURL, explode);    
   [self performSelector:@selector(playsfx) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

 -(void)playsfx {

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundID(explode)
      }
```

But for some reason the sound never plays.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID`, which doesn't play a sound, just creates an ID for it. Use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(explode);`.

Comment: im sorry i copied the wrong code i already DO use audioservicesplaysystemsoundid i just copied it wrong sorry

Comment: Ah, in that case I'm not sure. What happens if you try AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(explode); immediately after creating the system sound?

Comment: when i updated to xcode 4.2 this code stopped working (the sounds stop playing) because MAYBE, before i didnt have to put __bridge, so that might be the reason, because of the __bridge, what does it even mean?